# Ball joint did not fit as deep on the new control arm

Tags: honda, ball-joint

I just changed the lower control arm on my 2007 Accord EX today. I bought the part from Amazon: Moog RK640290 Control Arm, I checked the new part with the old part and everything look identical but I noticed the ball joint did not go in as deep on the new lower control arm (maybe like 5mm shorter) because I could only put one side of the pin in instead of both side. I want to ask if it's normal and ok to drive like that? [image: Picture]

Comment: Was there paint in the hole for the ball joint? If so, this little bit of filler in the hole could have prevented the ball from seating all the way.

Comment: there wasn't paint in the hole but paint on both side of the hole.

Comment: I was just concerned with the inside of the hole, not on the facing parts. Since the hole itself is in a wedge shape (or conical, I guess), if there is paint inside the cone, it could cause what you are talking about by not allowing the ball joint to seat fully. Since you said it was clean on the inside, this would preclude this from happening.

Comment: What did you torque the castle nut to?

Comment: I torque it to 50 ft lb

Answer (score 1):

Is the ball joint nut torqued up to spec?. 
The ball joint should fit very closely to the way the previous one fitted, and you should definitely be able to insert the split pin normally. 
You need to double check that the arm is indeed correct and that its specs are comparable to the original one. Thicker material around the ball joint socket or a narrower hole in the lower arm will cause this issue. Something is not right here so measurements need taking to identify the exact issue. I would suggest perhaps a faulty new part has been supplied.

Comment: Amazon said this should fit so most likely faulty part then. darn it, took me a while to get the new arm in there.

Comment: I'd agree and say that as long as the cotter pin can be installed nicely, it's fine (you're not at risk of the nut falling off). In this case, personally, I'd leave it be as it meets the requirements and then check in on it in a week or so and make sure everything's still tight and looking ok. If you can't get the cotter pin installed properly, then all bets are off; return it.

Comment: Dangit, just re-read your post. Apparently I missed the part about the pin. You can't get it in so return the arm. My guess is the manufacturer didn't drill the hole properly for the ball joint. If you end up needing to pick a different brand, Proforged is excellent but they're much pricier. Moog is typically good; Beck/Arnley and Dorman aren't bad in my opinion.

Comment: @atraudes Yea, the replacement part is on the way already. Quick question can bad control arm bushing cause vibration?

Comment: It will not directly cause vibration but it will add to any suspension vibration say when you're travelling along an uneven road or one that is full of holes.. If say the wheel is out of balance already then a worn control arm bush will amplify it.